# Issue with local discovery of devices on dockerized Syncthing

Tags: networking, docker, container, syncthing

I'm trying to set up a Syncthing instance for my local use and so I don't want to run a discovery server. For the local discovery of devices, Syncthing advertises itself over broadcast IP address of the network it is connected to. The problem is that all the docker containers reside within the DockerNet, which is Docker's virtualised network.

This is `ifconfig`'s result on my host machine.

```
root@deltastation:~# ifconfig
docker0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        inet6 fe80::42:d9ff:fe53:d961  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 02:42:d9:53:d9:61  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 55574  bytes 71707185 (68.3 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 43881  bytes 3441923 (3.2 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.101  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 fe80::1dea:8489:d94a:35df  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 02:81:af:f1:00:09  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 45779  bytes 3638460 (3.4 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 62916  bytes 72948919 (69.5 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 38
```

As you can see here, the dockerized syncthing keeps advertising itself on 172.17.255.255 while the client resides on 192.168.0.0 network. Any idea on how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syncthing's [README-Docker.md](https://github.com/syncthing/syncthing/blob/master/README-Docker.md) states:

> To allow local discovery, the docker **host network** can be used instead:
>
> ```
> $ docker pull syncthing/syncthing
> $ docker run --network=host \
>     -v /wherever/st-sync:/var/syncthing \
>     syncthing/syncthing:latest
> ```

A working Docker `stack.yml` looks like this:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  syncthing:
    image: "syncthing/syncthing"
    networks:
      hostnet: {}
    ports:
    - target: 8384
      published: 8384
      protocol: "tcp"
      mode: "host"
    - target: 22000
      published: 22000
      protocol: "tcp"
      mode: "host"
    - target: 21027
      published: 21027
      protocol: "udp"
      mode: "host"
    volumes:
    - "syncthing-data:/var/syncthing/"
    - "/mnt/Sync/:/mnt/Sync/"
networks:
  hostnet:
   external: true
   name: host
```

Answer (score 1):

I use the [linuxserver.io syncthing docker image](https://docs.linuxserver.io/images/docker-syncthing). To enable local discovery of syncthing instances, I have adjusted the docker-compose config and added the `network_mode: host` line:

```
---
version: "2.1"
services:
  syncthing:
    image: linuxserver/syncthing
    container_name: syncthing
    hostname: syncthing #optional
    environment:
      - PUID=1000
      - PGID=1000
      - TZ=Europe/London
    volumes:
      - /path/to/appdata/config:/config
      - /path/to/data1:/data1
      - /path/to/data2:/data2
    ports:
      - 8384:8384
      - 22000:22000
      - 21027:21027/udp
    restart: unless-stopped
    network_mode: host
```